# Admin and Meta don't see the fields of parent abstract classes

Tags: django, python-3.x, inheritance, django-models

I use Django 1.10. I have the following model structure:

```
class GenericPage(models.Model):
    """Abstract page, other pages inherit from it."""
    book = models.ForeignKey('Book', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class GenericColorPage(models.Model):
    """Abstract page that is sketchable and colorable, other pages inherit from it."""
    sketched = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    colored = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class GenericBookPage(GenericColorPage):
    """A normal book page, with a number. Needs to be storyboarded and edited."""

    ###
    #various additional fields
    ###

    class Meta:
        # unique_together = (('page_number', 'book'),) # impedes movement of pages
        ordering = ('-book', '-page_number',)
        abstract = True

    objects = BookPageManager()  # the manager for book pages

class BookPage(GenericBookPage):
    """Just a regular book page with text (that needs to be proofread)"""
    proofread = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Additionally, an excerpt from Admin:

```
class BookPageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # fields NOT to show in Edit Page.
    list_display = ('__str__', 'page_name', 'sketched', 'colored', 'edited', 'proofread',)
    list_filter = ('book',)
    readonly_fields = ('page_number',)  # valid page number is assigned via overridden save() in model
    actions = ['delete_selected',]
```

I tried to do `./manage.py makemigrations` but if throws the following errors:

```
<class 'progress.admin.BookPageAdmin'>: (admin.E116) The value of 'list_filter[0]' refers to 'book', which does not refer to a Field.
progress.BookPage: (models.E015) 'ordering' refers to the non-existent field 'book'.
```

In the past, when I did not use the abstracts and just put everything into `BookPage` model, it all worked fine. But it seems that Meta and Admin don't see the fields in parent classes. Am I missing something? Is there a way to make them read fields from abstract parents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In the past, when I did not use the abstracts and just put everything into BookPage model, it all worked fine

Of course it worked fine because you put everything inside `BookPage` which is not an [abstract class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes) which means that table (and, thus, fields) will be created.

> But it seems that Meta and Admin don't see the fields in parent classes. Am I missing something?

You're missing the fact that none of your models inherits from the `GenericPage` abstract model. Thus, the `book` field is never created.

> Is there a way to make them read fields from abstract parents?

You must create/modify a model that inherits from an abstract model. Maybe, do this:

```
class GenericBookPage(GenericColorPage, GenericPage):
```

which allows you to inherit both `GenericColorPage` and `GenericPage` fields. When I say inherit I mean when the `migrate` command runs to actually create the database table and the relevant columns (model fields).

Comment: Oh, boy, I've made a mistake there. It should be `GenericColorPage(GenericPage):` instead! I almost thought that Django was unable to traverse the tree of abstracts, but there was no tree in the first place. Thanks for pointing it out!